# Why do I get NZEC error here?

Tags: c++, input, runtime-error

My code here-

```
     void input(char* m)
{
    char ch;
    do
    {
        ch=getchar();
    }
    while(ch=='\n');
    int i=0;
    while(ch!='\n')
    {
        m[i++]=ch;
        ch=getchar();
    }
}
```

gives NZEC error. However, if I limit the input with a character count **len**, such as this-

```
void input(char* m, int len)
{
    char ch;
    do
    {
        ch=getchar();
    }
    while(ch=='\n');
    int i=0;
    while(ch!='\n'&&i<len-1)
    {
        m[i++]=ch;
        ch=getchar();
    }
}
```

it passes along fine. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case you have a buffer overflow !

Your `while(ch!='\n')` will loop until a '\n' regardless of the number of chars typed in. If more chars are typed than there is space in the char buffer pointed to by `m`, you might corrupt memory.  Of course, in the second case, `len` will avoid this.

Please note that in both cases, you do not ensure a null terminator to your buffer.  So if you process youd `m` as c-string you might also get not enough memory or a bufer overflow, as the string could be extremely long.

Have you ever considered defining your function as:

```
void input(std::string& m) {
    // ...
    m.push_back(ch); // instead of m[i++]=ch 
    // ...  
}
```

Comment: The string's value is known beforehand. It wont exceed the buffer. But what I wanted to know was how does adding a length parameter avoid that runtime error? Their could still be buffer overflow.

Comment: Because in the length parameter you pass the maximum length of your buffer, and the loop would finish when you've reached them, even if ther's still no '\n'.

Comment: Theoretically, the length parameter could be arbitrary. It may well exceed the buffer size. I understand the syntax.

Comment: Of course nothing prevents `len` to be inconsistent with the real buffer size. If it isn't major crashes are in sight ! This is why I suggested the safe alternative of a reference to a `std::string` as this type manages its length by itself.

Comment: I understand that. But what I'm looking for is a reason for the compiler's behaviour, not an alternative.